# R markdown, beamer_presentation can't start new page

Tags: r, latex, beamer

I'm actually  working on a presentation that should be done with RMD.
I have a problem with content.
I have a slide, which a lot of content (too much to get displayed in the same slide). So the content  overflows the page
So I want to start a new page but I can't do it.
I tried to use all suggestions that I could read on the net, but nothing worked successfully.
`\newpage`, `\clearpage`, `\pagebreak`, ...

Here are the parameters of my beamer presentation:

```
---
title: "project"
subtitle: "my subtitle"
author: "Berni"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    toc: true
    slide_level: 2
    
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways:

- Plan your slide so it fits on the page. Either by using two different frames or using beamer overlays to specify which content should be on which slide of the frame
- and then there is the evil `allowframebreaks` option. With this option, beamer will automaticaly split the frame if the slide becomes too full. Or you can manually force a split with `\framebreak`. You shouldn't use this. Frames should be carefully planed and not randomly be broken where beamer things it might be a good idea. Also many strange problems can occur, don't complain if you run into one of them.

---

```
---
title: "project"
subtitle: "my subtitle"
author: "Berni"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    toc: true
    slide_level: 2 
---

## frametitle

\only<1>{first slide}

\only<2>{second slide}

## Evil! {.allowframebreaks}

something 

\framebreak

something else
```